# CRC in sector of a usb pendrive

Tags: usb

I am trying to check for the data integrity in fat32 filesystem.Currently I have implemented fat on lpc2478. For the checking of data integrity, I come to know that each sector of a disk has checksum or CRC.But I wanted to find the location of the CRC in the sector.Can you please advice  me on how to find the location of the CRC in a sector of usb pendrive? and will this CRC change with manufacturer of the pendrive.?

EDIT

Oh! thanks for your reply! Is there a way to find out the CRC zone alone. using some editors like winhex?I tried using winhex to find out the zone, but in vain. If this is such a complicated case and prone to hazards,Is there any other way of checking the data integrity?

Comment: Oh! thanks for your reply! Is there a way to find out the CRC zone alone. using some editors like winhex?I tried using winhex to find out the zone, but in vain. If this is such a complicated case and prone to hazards,Is there any other way of checking the data integrity?

Comment: By the way, I got one doubt. Is the CRC check goes on like, flash(CRC)->usb controller(implemented by manufacturers). so the controller will give me the errors caused and so I no need to check for data integrity ???

Answer (score 1):

While several file systems-- such as ZFS, UBIFS, HAMMER, Btrfs, etc.  -- do use CRC or other checksum, my understanding is FAT32 does not use any CRC or checksum.

So when you write code for your microcontroller that stores files in FAT32-compatible format on a pen drive, you don't need to calculate a CRC or checksum.

The microcontroller inside the pen drive calculates the CRC for you when you write to a sector, and checks it for you when you read a sector.
My understanding is that all modern rotating-disk drives and sata SSDs and pendrives do use internal proprietary error-detection-and-correction information.
That information is used internally by the microcontroller in those devices.
However, that information never leaves those devices.
That EDAC information is stored outside the data sectors,
and can't be read by the main CPU -- you'll never see that information.
Manufacturers have the freedom to switch to an improved wear-leveling and EDAC system internally, and still present the same interface to the main CPU.

The SATA interface and the Ultra DMA PATA interface and the USB interface use CRC to detect errors in data transfer between the drive microcontroller and the main CPU -- but that CRC information is generated on-the-fly by the transmitting CPU, and is not actually stored on the media.

Which one of the following will work best for your application?:

- implement FAT32 alone, and rely on the microcontroller inside the pen drive to handle EDAC.
- implement FAT32, and store the data in a file format that includes checksums to detect errors -- such as the ".ZIP" file format. (There is an "uncompressed" option that simply stores the raw data and the checksum).
- implement FAT32, and with each file "filename" also store a very small corresponding digest file (a kind of checksum) -- a "filename.sha" that [sha256sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sha256sum) can verify, or a "filename.md5" that [md5sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/md5sum) can verify. ([md5deep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/md5deep) can verify either kind of digest). To detect errors.
- implement FAT32, and with each file or group of files also store parity files such that [Parchive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) can detect any errors, and also (if it's not too badly corrupted) repair them.
- implement some other [file system with a built-in checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#File_systems_with_built_in_fault-tolerance) or CRC.
- implement FAT32, and store each file on two physically separate pen drives that should always contain exactly the same data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated case in Flash memory

Each flash drive IC maps out sectors in its own way and is not a block like on a hard drive where 1 Logical Sector is contained in its Physical Sector which is in its own Zone.

Flash memory has zones- but they are mapped out randomly to reduce stress on the nand. There will be a separate part of the flash that has a CRC zone that correlates to each Logical Sectors so it conforms to the IDE/LBA standard.

So in a nut shell - if its on a IDE bus Driver  use that to Query for CRC- do not try and go to sector lever of the Flash because you will hit a brick wall. If its mounted Via a USB you might have some problems.